# json as table with django

Tags: python, html, json, django

I have modeled my database using models.py within my django project, one of the fields is a JSONField and I can save json data into that field without any problem. My doubt comes in how I can show that information as an html table. At the moment I have been using ListView to show that information in a template but I don't know how to transform it into a table.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
It's also best to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you.
That also shows what you have done so far and at which specific problem you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `object.json_field.items` you can loop through them just like a normal dictonary / can also use `.keys` and `.values`

#### Example use in a table

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Key</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for k, v in object.json_field.items %}
            <tr>
                <th>{{k}}</th>
                <th>{{v}}</th>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```